# Failed login session when using twitter-connect plugin with Ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

i'v try using twitter connect plugin but it does't work 
i'v error `failed login session`
i'v also get fabric key 
so any solution for this to get twitter authentication and login with it.
this is my code:

```
loginWithTwitter(){

  this.tw.login().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
    //Get user data
    this.tw.showUser().then(function(user){
      //Save the user data in NativeStorage

      this.storage.setItem('twitter_user',
      {
        name: user.name,
        userName: user.screen_name,
        picture: user.profile_image_url_https
      }).then(function() {      
        console.log("twitter");
      })
    }, function(error){

  });
})

}
```

and this my config file

```
<plugin name="twitter-connect-plugin" spec="https://github.com/chroa/twitter-connect-plugin">
    <variable name="FABRIC_KEY" value="ddb30e3efa7732b38e327c75a3ce57fd4c688ee1" />
    <variable name="TWITTER_KEY" value="twitter key" />
    <variable name="TWITTER_SECRET" value="twitter secret" />
</plugin>
```

any solutions?

Comment: `loginWithTwitter()` written in `typescript` or `javascript` ?

Comment: @hrdkisback typescript

Comment: In `typescript` i think it should be `.then((user) =>` not `.then(function(user)`.

Comment: no, it is not the problem

Comment: https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/twitter-connect-plugin/issues/16

Comment: Did you used it with firebase?

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me is to set **Callback URL** to `twittersdk://` and to enable Sign in with Twitter from [The Twitter Application Management](https://apps.twitter.com/):

[image]

Source: https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic-twitter-login

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Adding twittersdk:// as the callback URL got things working again. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ionic 4, however I faced the same issue on Ionic 3 as well. Rather than adding the following in config.xml

```html
<plugin name="twitter-connect-plugin" spec="https://github.com/chroa/twitter-connect-plugin">
    <variable name="FABRIC_KEY" value="ddb30e3efa7732b38e327c75a3ce57fd4c688ee1" />
    <variable name="TWITTER_KEY" value="twitter key" />
    <variable name="TWITTER_SECRET" value="twitter secret" />
</plugin>
```

try adding the following along with the other preferences

```html
 <preference name="TwitterConsumerKey" value="twitter key" />
<preference name="TwitterConsumerSecret" value="twitter secret" />
```

Comment: How can we get FABRIC_KEY ? Please explain in detail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: While using the new Twitter API, the preference entries were of great help